# I cannot over write the text for the months names in tx_news list view

Tags: localization, typo3, translation, typo3-12.x

My installation:
TYPO3 12.4.11
News 11.4.1
PHP 8.2.15

I want to overwrite the months names in this language file:
`typo3conf/l10n/da/news/Resources/Private/Language/da.locallang.xlf`

For example, I try to change `January` to `Jannewaris` to create: `01 Jannewaris 2024` for the news item date.
No matter what I try I cannot do it.

I have this in my setup, it does work:
`plugin.tx_news.\_LOCAL_LANG.da.dateFormat = %d %B -%Y.`
It spells the name of the month (`01 January 2024`) instead of displaying `01.01.2024`, but I want to change the spelling from `January` with `Jannewaris`.

For example I try to change `month.01`
I change the name for January in the file: `typo3conf/l10n/da/news/Resources/Private/Language/da.locallang.xlf`
as shown below.

```xml
<trans-unit id="month.01" xml:space="preserve" approved="yes">
   <source>January</source>
   <target state="final">Jannewaris</target>
</trans-unit>
```

The above code does not change `January` to `Jannewaris`, the correct spelling for **danish** is still shown.
I use the below block of code in: `Partials/List/list.html`

```xml
<time itemprop="datePublished" 
      class="event-fa-time" 
      datetime="{f:format.date(date:newsItem.datetime, format:'Y-m-d')}"> 
   <f:format.date format="{f:translate(key:'dateFormat')}" >{newsItem.datetime}</f:format.date>
</time>
```

In TS Setup I have tried using this script:
`plugin.tx_news.\_LOCAL_LANG.da.month.01 = Jannewaris`

It does not have any effect either. I still cannot change the text to `Jannewaris`

How do I make a change to the spelling of the month?

Where does TYPO3 / tx_news get the month names from?

If I remove the file `typo3conf/l10n/da/news/Resources/Private/Language/da.locallang.xlf` the months are still displayed on the front-end for the **da** language.

Can anyone tell me how is it done?
I have no idea how / where Typo3 is generating the month names?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you use the PHP function `strftime()` (which is the case if you use a format like `%d %B -%Y`) the name of the month comes from the operating system. To get the matching spelling you need to configure the matching locale setting.
Get the list of available locales by `locale -a` from the command line.

If you want to use your language strings you need to 'translate' it on your own:
Get the number of the month and use it for the translation-key:
`<f:translate key="month.{f:format.date(format:'m', base:newsItem.datetime)}" />`

---

EDIT:

you could define a partial/section for it:

```xml
<f:section name="myFormattedDate">
  <f:comment> 
    expected argument: 'datePar'
    white space formating may need rework
    and the translate VH may need `extensionName` or full path in the `key`
  </f:comment>

  <f:format.date format="d" base="{datePar}" /> 
  <f:translate key="month.{f:format.date(format:'m', base:datePar)}" /> 
  <f:format.date format="Y" base="{datePar}" /> 
</f:section>
```

Comment: Hi, I confirm I want to use the language string. I added <f:translate key="month.{f:format.date(format:'m', base:newsItem.datetime)}" /> to the file list.html. It did not have any effect. I'm afraid I do not know how to use it. I don't know if need typo3 script in the setup for it to function.

Comment: If possible my goal is to use this file: /l10n/da/news/Resources/Private/Language/da.locallang.xlf. Change the spelling of the months (month.01 etc.) and display these on the front-end. I also want to show the abbreviated names as in Apr instead of April. I use the file da.locallang.xlf for the Frisian language, this is why I need to change the spelling.

Comment: the easier way is to use the locale of your server operating system, where the local language (danish) should be available.
the alternative could be complicated as you need more than just a fomat-string for dates. you need three separate strings (day, month, year) each time you want to show a date (which could be made easier if you define a partial for it).

Comment: for **frisian** I have found the locale codes `fy` and `fy_NL`

Comment: Thank you, I cannot use the local language danish, because I need to show the months in the Frisian language. I have used the Danish language in my install, but I re-write the Danish language files (locallang.xlf) to Frisian where need. Till now it has worked. Only the news dates haven't worked. I am puzzled in the news language file all the months are included Ex:<trans-unit id="month.01" xml:space="preserve" approved="yes"> <source>January</source>
            <target state="final">Jannewaris</target></trans-unit>  but I am unable to use them. Is it not possible make of these?

Comment: (for frisian I have found the locale codes fy and fy_NL). How can I use theses now I use danish language files? I don't think users systems have the frisian language installed to their systems. I have this in my site config: languages:
  -
    title: Fryske
    enabled: true
    languageId: 0
    base: /
    typo3Language: da
    locale: da_DK.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: da
    navigationTitle: Fryske
    hreflang: da-DK
    direction: ''
    flag: blue
  -

Comment: For the month names it would be necessary that your operating system supports the frisian language (which probably will not do). Therefore you probably need the partial/section solution from my answer.

Comment: if you use frisian and not danish you should configure and label your website with the correct language. **that may include to define all language files to your new language.** But the TYPO3 project would be glad to add another language in the core :)

Comment: I do not have the knowledge to do  "partial/section solution" as you suggest above. Thanks for your help anyway

Comment: It would be fantastic if the TYPO3 project could add the Frisian language to the core. How do I ask for this?

Comment: if you do FLUID and use Viewhelpers you do partials/sections. (`partials` are FLUID files in the partials folder. `sections` are separate sections (tag `f:section`) in a FLUID file like a function in programming code. the call is done with the `f:render` viewhelper https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/12.4/en-us/typo3fluid/fluid/latest/Render.html.

Comment: for additional languages: look at the tip at the end of https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/12.4/en-us/ApiOverview/Localization/Languages.html